# Removing a write statement is causing my program to crash

Tags: fortran, nan, underflow

I've got a bit of a weird issue occurring within my code, and I've never had an issue like this before. I have a program that calculates two bodies orbiting under their own gravity and within the do-loop, which I use to calculate their motion over time, I have a write statement that writes data to a file to plot later. However, I've recently wanted to removed the write statement but when I remove it, the program crashes after a few calculations with the data being filled with NaNs. I'll add a few lines below.

```
 open(unit=100,file=datafile)  !open file with name datafile (#)

 do while(ctime<totaltime)     !loop until current time > total time 
   call calc_semimajor(Objects, a)     !calculate semimajor axis
   call calc_ecc(Objects, evector, e)  !calculate eccentricty 

   at = (a0**4 - (264.0d0/5.0d0)*beta_time*ctime)**0.25 
   write(100,*) ctime, Objects(1:2), a, at, e  !write to file (#)

   !some 
   !more 
   !lines
   !here... 

 end do

 close(100) !close datafile (#)
```

I have this loop stored within a subroutine for reference but it's never been an issue before with other programs I've made. I've tried changing the unit number that hasn't worked. I've stop passing in the datafile character argument and just defined the file as 'data.txt' within the subroutine that hasn't worked. I've tried copying it as plain text and recompling with gfortran, that hasn't worked. I did compile with nagfor and that gave an underflow error and managed to calculate a few more timesteps before crashing but that error disappears when I remove the comments for lines involving unit=100 (labelled with (#)). I've even tried re-writing the enitre program to see if I've missed something but I keep getting this issue even when rewriting with no open() statements. I do have some constants stored within a module that are inputted with the subroutine if that might be an issue? I'm sorry if this has been worded poorly but I was just wondering if anyone has ever had this issue before within Fortran, and if so, how could I solve it?

Thanks!

Edit: I've used valgrind to help locate the issue. (Compiling with the -g flag before) and that gave this repeating error

```
  `==14846== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised       value(s) 
   ==14846== by 0x40131B: leapfrog_ (/path/to/file)
   ==14846== by 0x40353C: MAIN__ (/path/to/file)
   ==14846== by 0x403939: main (/path/to/file)
   ==14846== Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation 
   ==14846== at 0x401C12: calc_pnacceleration_ (/path/to/file)
```

I've added in an interface for the subroutines and placed dummy variables within the subroutines as opposed to using the same variable names from the main body. This hasn't resolved the issue. However, one thing that I have noticed is that if I complied with the optimisation flag (-O3) the error disappears and it runs for the total time specified. Could this indicate any particular error?

Second Edit: I've added the output when compiling with `gfortran -Wall -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace`

```
Simulation: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: 
(.text+0x0): first defined here
Simulation: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o: 
(.fini+0x0): first defined here
Simulation:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: 
(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
Simulation: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: 
(.data+0x0): first defined here
Simulation: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined 
here 
Simulation: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o: 
(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `calc_ecc_':
/path/to/file/Simulation.f90:441: multiple definition of `calc_ecc_'
Simulation:(.text+0xf6): first defined here
/tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `crossproduct_':
/path/to/file/Simulation.f90:466: multiple definition of 
`crossproduct_'
Simulation:(.text+0x1624): first defined here
/tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `leapfrog_':
/path/to/file/Simulation.f90:262: multiple definition of `leapfrog_'
Simulation:(.text+0x26d): first defined here
/tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `calc_pnacceleration_':
/path/to/file/Simulation.f90:358: multiple definition of 
`calc_pnacceleration_'
Simulation:(.text+0xe57): first defined here
/tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `calc_semimajor_':
/path/to/file/Simulation.f90:426: multiple definition of 
`calc_semimajor_'
 Simulation:(.text+0xd8b): first defined here
 /tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `dotproduct_':
 /path/to/file/Simulation.f90:479: multiple definition of 
 `dotproduct_'
 Simulation:(.text+0x15c1): first defined here
 /tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `calc_deltaphigr_':
 /path/to/file/Simulation.f90:415: multiple definition of 
 `calc_deltaphigr_'
 Simulation:(.text+0x16ed): first defined here
 /tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `main':
 /path/to/file/Simulation.f90:25: multiple definition of `main'
 Simulation:(.text+0x2be5): first defined here
 /tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `plotdata_':
 /path/to/file/Simulation.f90:231: multiple definition of 
 `plotdata_'
 Simulation:(.text+0x2c20): first defined here
 /tmp/ccDIKQQB.o: In function `writeline_':
 /path/to/file/Simulation.f90:490: multiple definition of `writeline_'
 Simulation:(.text+0x3418): first defined here
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0):  
 multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
 Simulation:(.data+0x18): first defined here
 /usr/bin/ld: error in Simulation(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table 
 will be created.
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: That is very weird behaviour. Compile it with options `gfortran -Wall -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace` -- with a little bit of luck, this will give you more information on what's going wrong.

Comment: Actually, what is `Objects` -- and how is it converted to a string for writing?

Comment: Generally such behaviour indicates memory leaks or related ([heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)). I would compile your program with the line indicated by @chw21, and then let valgrind crunch it. `valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out`

Comment: Objects is an array that I use to store the position, velocities, and acceleration for each coordinate. So 1,2,3 are x,y,z; 4,5,6 are velocity in x,y,z, and 7,8,9 are acceleration in x,y,z

Comment: Ok, so I ran with gfortran -Wall -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace and I got a few errors, it states that there are multiple definitions of the subroutine throughout my program. I've added an interface to the main body to see if that'll solve it, however, it does not. I get the same errors.

Comment: I've run valgrind --leak-check = full, and I get the following repeating error `==14846== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14846==    by 0x40131B: leapfrog_ 
==14846==    by 0x40353C: MAIN__ 
==14846==    by 0x403939: main 
==14846==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14846==    at 0x401C12: calc_pnacceleration_                                                I've removed that path as it's too long for stackoverflow. So I assume it would seem there's some error with my calc_pnacceleration subrouinte?

Comment: @kvantour Leaks are something different and do not cause any bugs. They just eat up memory. What you are referring to is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma96 You have to compile with `-g` before using valgrind. Please [edit] your question to contain the new info, do not use comments.

Comment: @VladimirF you are correct.

Comment: I've added the multiple definitions to a second edit @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: Unless you show a real [mcve] no-one can help you. We can only tell you to use a debugger. Also show the actual and *complete* commands you use for compiling. Including the file names and everything else. Complete.

Comment: I'll upload the code as an edit!

Comment: put your subroutines in a module and `use` it.  Nobody (including you) wants to painstakingly check that all your `interface` code actually matches exactly the subroutine codes.

Comment: If you have bugs such as (but not limited to) undefined values and array bounds violations, the behavior is almost guaranteed to change when a write() prevents optimization.  The answer below seems specific to gfortran where some of the checks you need require -O.  With other compilers it may be better to debug without -O at first.

Comment: To my way of thinking OP has gone wrong defining interfaces for each subroutine.  A much better approach would have been to put them into module(s) and then `use` them, and to let the compiler make the interfaces.  These days I only write interfaces when I want to wrap multiple procedures behind the same generic interface and, just occasionally, when wrapping old code.  Neither seems to apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your code with the following options:
`-Wall -fcheck=all -g -O -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=invalid`
Fix all warnings.  When you running the code use 'y' and '1'
as your inputs.  When it dies because of the use of uninitialized
variables.  Use `gdb` to look at the core dump.

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer ?

Comment: Is this intended to be a rhetorical question? OP did not go wrong with the use of an interface block instead of a module.  OP is using uninitializes variables.  Putting the subroutines in a module will not magically fix unitialized variables.  tim18, minimum required options to find the issues are -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=invalid.  Other compilers have similar options.

Comment: If you did find the actual mistake then show it here. It is useful to teach someone how to debug, but that can be in a comment. Or in a half of the answer. But the OP asked where is his error not how to debug. Why to hide it when you, I assume, already found it?

Comment: No, not a rhetorical question at all.  It's not clear to me that what you have written answers the question.  It seems that at least one other reader wasn't sure either.

Comment: HP Mark, I've provided sufficient information that the OP should be able to debug his/her code.  There are several uninitialized variables, except that -finit-real=nan initialized the otherwise uninitialized variables. Vl

Comment: Vladimir, I tried to include the first frame from the debugging session, but SO gave me a silly error and suggested that I format the code.  With inputs of 'y' and '1', the code dies at line 337. At least one of a possible three variables is an NaN.

Comment: SO just wants you to format your text you pass, that's all. That is the correct behaviour. Do not just paste anything without formatting. It just takes one click on `{}` in the question editor.  Read the hepful messages it gives you and the help pages like the Welcome [tour].